# Magento2 URL Key not getting updated for 1 store

Tags: magento2, url-key

Magento2 I am facing a strange issue were URL Key is not getting updated in 1 store (Arabic) when I update the product URL from All Store Views.

As soon as I change the URL key from All store views & save the product it gets updated in Englist store, All store view but not Arabic store.

Not sure how to debug this issue.

Comment: You have given the specific URL for a specific store?

Comment: No it is taking the global value

Comment: ok you can go in Arabic store view section and check your default value check box is clicked or not?

Comment: it is clicked ...

Comment: ok so you can flush the cache and reindex command run

Comment: I noticed it is for default store only..